# Bad request [400] for Twillio channel in Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, azure, twilio, botframework, azure-bot-service

I was trying to set up a prod and dev environments for my bot app with Twilio channels tied to an Azure Bot when I started getting this error on my prod env.

Error: POST to 'https://sms.botframework.com/v3/conversations/..../' failed: [400] Bad Request

[image: VsCode debugging]

Steps taken:

1. The code is exactly the same between my prod and dev envs
2. Verified that the configuration parameters are the same among the two.
3. Checked that Twilio isn't getting any errors.
4. Routed calls locally to my dev box and looked at the address the msg is being sent.. looks fine.

Next
Will look into what the actual request.. hopefully it will help me figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Turned out the error was that when wiring up things on Twilio, I missed to correctly point the prod TwiMl App correctly to the right number. This can be done in Phone Numbers > Manage Numbers > Active Numbers

[image]

After that you should head to Portal.Azure.com and delete the Twilio channel to then add it again.

[image]

That fixed it for me. Cheers! :)